# What is $g$ when traveling quickly around a planet?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

> I am trying to model a rocket orbiting a planet. I want to simplify the problem so that the rocket is travelling along an infinitely long flat surface with a $g$ along the $y$-axis.

This is what I have done. Suppose the rocket is orbiting the planet. The relationship between $r$ (distance to the center of the planet), $v$ (the speed perpendicular to the line from the rocket to the center of the planet) and $g$ (gravitational acceleration) is $$g = \frac{v^2}{r}$$ If the rocket is powered on for a short while, the speed will decrease, and we "need" a smaller g for it to follow a circular orbit path. So I have set up this relationship. Here, $g_S$ is the gravitational acceleration in the simplified model:

$$ g - g_S = \frac{v^2}{r} $$
$$ g_S = -\frac{v^2}{r} + g $$
$$ g_S = -\frac{v^2}{r} + \frac{\gamma M}{r^2} $$
We multiply with the mass to get the gravitational force. $M$ is the mass of the planet.
$$ G_S = -\frac{mv^2}{r} + \frac{\gamma Mm}{r^2} $$

[image]

Is my reasoning correct? It all depends on whether or not the function $g = v^2 / r$ applies in this situation.

Comment: I do not understand why you did not used $g-g_F=\frac{v^2}{r}-\frac{v_F^2}{r_F}$

Comment: @julianfernandez Where did you get this formula from?

Comment: from your own definition. if $g=\frac{v^2}{r}$ then $g_F$ should be $\frac{v_F^2}{r_F}$

Comment: @julianfernandez The formula $g=\frac{v^2}{r}$ doesn't apply that way (if I'm not mistaken). The formula states what the gravitational acceleration must be to achieve a circular orbit. I.e. $v = \sqrt{gr} = \sqrt{\frac{\gamma M}{r}}$ is the velocity an object needs to have to orbit a planet with mass $M$ $r$ meters above the center of the planet.

Comment: Hi Friend of Kim. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Then I do not get what is the definition $g_F$, I thought it was the new g needed to sustain a lower orbit.

Comment: @julianfernandez In the illustration $G = g_F \cdot m$. So $g_F$ is the gravitational acceleration in the simplified model.

Comment: @julianfernandez So if the rocket is orbiting the planet, $g_F=0$. This means that in the simplified model, the rocket would just float in mid-air. Whether or not this simplication holds all depends on the usage of $g = v^2/r$.

Comment: yes, I get that, but you define that at the end. What is the definition (or meaning) of $g_F$ when you introduce it for the first time in the equation I mentioned? ("is the gravitational acceleration in the simplified model" is not clear to me, so, am I correct when I assume that it is the new g needed to sustain a lower orbit

Comment: I do not think it makes sense, why is the acceleration $g=\frac{v^2}{r}$ in the original orbit and then zero in a lower orbit? Plus I do not understand how you can state that in the simplified approximation the rocket just float in mid air. Had the gravity force just disappear? why?

Comment: @julianfernandez I've renamed $G_F$ to $G_S$ where $S$ stands for simplified model. The simplified model is the one I've illustrated. $G$ in the image is the $G_S$.

Comment: Just want to say that unless $G_S$ is always zero by that equation, you won't have a circular orbit. In a circular orbit, the centripetal force equals the gravitational force (unless other forces are strong enough to influence. But they rarely are)

Comment: What I mean by this is if the rocket is in any periodic orbit, then a simplified model equating it to moving over a horizontal surface would have no net downwards acceleration due to gravity

Comment: I still cannot make sense of the equations, I apologize. Hope somebody will. Best.

Comment: @Jim I'm using the simplified model to model a rocket landing on a planet. So this is why I need a simplified model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically asking how to describe the equations of motion when viewed from an rotating frame of reference (the planets surface). This can be done by including the [Coriolis effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_effect).

For example if you simplify the problem to just the equator of the planet the equations of motion would then become:

$$
\ddot{x}=\frac{F_x}{m}-\frac{v_xv_y}{r},
$$
$$
\ddot{y}=\frac{F_y}{m}+\frac{v_x^2}{r}-\frac{GM}{r^2},
$$
where $\ddot{x}$ is the acceleration on the horizontal axis, $\ddot{y}$ is the acceleration on the vertical axis, $F_i$ the component of the applied force (drag or thrust ect.) in the $i$-direction, $m$ is the mass of the rocket, $v_i$ the component of the velocity in the $i$-direction, $G$ the gravitational constant, $M$ the mass of the planet and $r$ the distance from the center of mass of the planet to the rocket. However do keep in mind that these velocities are relative to the orbital velocities. So if you want to calculate it relative to the surface velocity you would have to add $r\omega$ to $v_x$, where $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the planet (usually in radians per second).

Comment: So the acceleration in the $y$-direction is correct. What you are saying in addition to what I've suggested is that $\ddot{x}$ is also affected by the velocity? How did you get this equation?

Comment: @FriendofKim yes, your vertical component of acceleration is correct (however I defined up as the positive direction, while you use downwards). Did you have a look at the Coriolis effect, since this can be derived from that, by assuming that you have no velocity component in the north/south direction.

Comment: @FriendofKim an easy way to intuitively understand the term of in $\ddot{x}$ is that it helps to conserve the [angular momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum) (if the other applied forces would be zero).